# 960 GS Removing Gap

Tags: html, css, margin, 960.gs

```css
/*
  960 Grid System ~ Core CSS.
  Learn more ~ http://960.gs/

  Licensed under GPL and MIT.
*/

/*
  Forces backgrounds to span full width,
  even if there is horizontal scrolling.
  Increase this if your layout is wider.

  Note: IE6 works fine without this fix.
*/

body {
  min-width: 960px;
}

/* `Container
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

/* `Grid >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.push_1, .pull_1,
.push_2, .pull_2,
.push_3, .pull_3,
.push_4, .pull_4,
.push_5, .pull_5,
.push_6, .pull_6,
.push_7, .pull_7,
.push_8, .pull_8,
.push_9, .pull_9,
.push_10, .pull_10,
.push_11, .pull_11 {
  position: relative;
}

/* `Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.alpha {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* `Grid >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .grid_1 {
  width: 60px;
}

.container_12 .grid_2 {
  width: 140px;
}

.container_12 .grid_3 {
  width: 220px;
}

.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.container_12 .grid_5 {
  width: 380px;
}

.container_12 .grid_6 {
  width: 460px;
}

.container_12 .grid_7 {
  width: 540px;
}

.container_12 .grid_8 {
  width: 620px;
}

.container_12 .grid_9 {
  width: 700px;
}

.container_12 .grid_10 {
  width: 780px;
}

.container_12 .grid_11 {
  width: 860px;
}

.container_12 .grid_12 {
  width: 940px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .prefix_1 {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_2 {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_3 {
  padding-left: 240px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_4 {
  padding-left: 320px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_5 {
  padding-left: 400px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_6 {
  padding-left: 480px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_7 {
  padding-left: 560px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_8 {
  padding-left: 640px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_9 {
  padding-left: 720px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_10 {
  padding-left: 800px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_11 {
  padding-left: 880px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .suffix_1 {
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_2 {
  padding-right: 160px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_3 {
  padding-right: 240px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_4 {
  padding-right: 320px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_5 {
  padding-right: 400px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_6 {
  padding-right: 480px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_7 {
  padding-right: 560px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_8 {
  padding-right: 640px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_9 {
  padding-right: 720px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_10 {
  padding-right: 800px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_11 {
  padding-right: 880px;
}

/* `Push Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .push_1 {
  left: 80px;
}

.container_12 .push_2 {
  left: 160px;
}

.container_12 .push_3 {
  left: 240px;
}

.container_12 .push_4 {
  left: 320px;
}

.container_12 .push_5 {
  left: 400px;
}

.container_12 .push_6 {
  left: 480px;
}

.container_12 .push_7 {
  left: 560px;
}

.container_12 .push_8 {
  left: 640px;
}

.container_12 .push_9 {
  left: 720px;
}

.container_12 .push_10 {
  left: 800px;
}

.container_12 .push_11 {
  left: 880px;
}

/* `Pull Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .pull_1 {
  left: -80px;
}

.container_12 .pull_2 {
  left: -160px;
}

.container_12 .pull_3 {
  left: -240px;
}

.container_12 .pull_4 {
  left: -320px;
}

.container_12 .pull_5 {
  left: -400px;
}

.container_12 .pull_6 {
  left: -480px;
}

.container_12 .pull_7 {
  left: -560px;
}

.container_12 .pull_8 {
  left: -640px;
}

.container_12 .pull_9 {
  left: -720px;
}

.container_12 .pull_10 {
  left: -800px;
}

.container_12 .pull_11 {
  left: -880px;
}

/* `Clear Floated Elements
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container_12:before,
.container_12:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after,
.container_12:after {
  clear: both;
}

/*
  The following zoom:1 rule is specifically for IE6 + IE7.
  Move to separate stylesheet if invalid CSS is a problem.
*/

.clearfix,
.container_12 {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960_12_col.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container_12 clearfix">
  <div class = "secondRow rightBox grid_6" style="background-color:green; text-align:center;">
   <p>About us</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "secondRow leftBox grid_6" style="background-color:red; text-align:center; float:right">
   <p>Products</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="960_12_col.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_12 clearfix">
        <div class = "secondRow rightBox grid_6 omega" style="background-color:green; text-align:center;">
            <p>About us</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "secondRow leftBox grid_6 alpha" style="background-color:red; text-align:center; float:right">
            <p>Products</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am using the 960.gs system and this produces two separate boxes, one green and one blue. 
Now, I did add the omega and alpha to try to remove the gap between the two boxes, but it did not work.

Now, how can I remove the gap between the boxes? or even better, can I control the gap between these boxes to a gap that I prefer?

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle.net for it?

Comment: I'm going to try that and learn how to @FlorinPop

Comment: The problem is that I can't test online your code, therefor I can't really help you. If you could find the CDN for 960.gs that would be also great.

Comment: I've found the CDN please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the:

```
float:right
```

from the div which contains the Products, that will remove the gap between the divs.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmw7saz7/1/).

Comment: But that doesn't remove the gap?

Comment: Sorry, I've uploaded a wrong jsfiddle. Please see now

Comment: now, what was the issue please if i may ask? Was it the float?

Comment: The float:right will push the item to the right maximum leaving there a space, even if you have 50%-50% width divs